# Regular expression does not match `]` symbol

Tags: regex, grep

My goal is to display only the text after last `]` symbol.

```
echo MY_TEXT | grep -o "[^\]]*$"
```

The output is just the last symbol.
If I change "]" symbol to any letter, it works as expected.

Examples:

```
$ echo Hello World | grep -o '[^o]*$'
rld  # and this is correct!
$ echo He]ll]o Wo]rld | grep -o "[^\]]*$"
d   # but expected: rld
```

Why behavior is different for symbol `o` and `]`?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to escape the `]`:

```
echo 'He]ll]o Wo]rld' | grep -o "[^]]*$"
```

Produces: `rld`

Answer (score 1):

At couple of thing: `[` doesn't need escaping inside a character class, you can use `--color` to see only the letters are match and notice `-o` splits each match on a new line:

```
$ echo "He]ll]o Wo]rld" | grep -o '[^]]*$'
rld

$ echo "He]ll]o Wo]rld" | grep --color '[^]]*'
He]ll]o Wo]rld

$ echo "He]ll]o Wo]rld" | grep -o '[^]]*'
He
ll
o Wo
rld
```

You can strip the `]` character using `tr` among many other ways:

```
$ echo "He]ll]o Wo]rld" | tr -d ']'
Hello World
```

Comment: Good answer, but note that the OP mentioned anchoring (`$`).

Answer (score 0):

Removed the escape character and it worked for me.

```
$ echo He]ll]o Wo]rld | grep -o "[^]]*$"
> rld
```